# Update Cart Count when product add to cart in header component automatically without refresh the page in angular 6

Tags: angular

I am developing E-Commerce application in angular 6.I want to update the shopping cart count in header component,when the product is add /remove from cart.Both are different component if i refresh the page then only the cart count is updated.I tried shared services to share data between these two component and tried subject concept also, but failed to get the count automatically.How to achieve this?

Cart Service.ts:

```
async getCart():Promise<HttpResponse<Object>> {
    const cartItems = await this.httpClient.get<HttpResponse<Object>>(this.endPointService.getCartItemURL, { observe :'response',withCredentials: true })
        .toPromise();
    return cartItems;
}
```

header.ts:

```
 cartItem: CartItem[];
ngOnInit() { 

      const cartItems = <HttpResponse<Object>>await this.cartService.getCart();
      this.cartItem = <CartItem[]>cartItems.body;
}
```

header.html:

```
  <span class='cart_count notification-counter' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">{{cartItem.length}}</span>
```

tried code:

cartService.ts

```
 private prodCount = 0;
    prodCountCountChange: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();
    UpdateCount(count: number) {
        this.prodCount = count;
        this.prodCountCountChange.next(this.prodCount);
    }
```

header.ts:

```
cartCount :any;
cartItem: CartItem[];
this.cartCount = this.cartService.UpdateCount(this.cartItem.length);
```

header.html:

```
  <span class='cart_count notification-counter' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">{{cartCount}}</span>
```

And also i tried the behaviour subject used in this link [angular view is not updating after component value gets changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944011/angular-view-is-not-updating-after-component-value-gets-changed.But) did not get desired output.

Comment: Why don't you use only observables? try returning Observable from `getCart()`.

Comment: I can't get you.how to returning Observable from getCart().

Comment: the link you tried there also service method return type is Observsable. Observables and Promises are diffrent https://angular.io/guide/comparing-observables#observables-compared-to-promises

Comment: Its my requirement to use promise.If there any way to achieve this using promise.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use your Subject correctly and your initial getCart() in Cart service.ts doesn't return a Promise but the result.

[edit]

available in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mip5sn)

Cart Service.ts:

```
// getCard should return only datas, not an httpResponse object
// and the result should be typed
getCart(): Promise<CartItem[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get(
      this.endPointService.getCartItemURL, 
      { observe :'response',withCredentials: true }
    ).pipe(
        map((httpResponse: HttpResponse<any>) => {
            this.updateCount(httpResponse.body.length); // Don't know how your cardItem[] is formatted
            return [].concat(httpResponse.body);
        })
    ).toPromise();
}

private prodCount: number = 0;
public prodCountCountChange: Subject<number> = new Subject();
updateCount(count: number = 0): void {
    this.prodCount = count;
    this.prodCountCountChange.next(this.prodCount);
}
```

header.ts:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    this.cartItem = await this.cartService.getCart();
    this.cartService.prodCountCountChange.subscribe(
        newProdCount => this.cartCount = newProdCount
    );
}
// and don't forget to unsubscribe
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.cartService.prodCountCountChange.unsubscribe();
}
```

header.html:

```
<span class='cart_count notification-counter' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">{{cartCount}}</span>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: not tested : can I help you debugging ? then I can update

Comment: Your cart service code is show the error.can you produce stackblitz for your solution.

Comment: Your code in stackblitz is also full of error.If i try change to <any[]>

Comment: ok, I did a mistake, yesterday, didn't save the last modifications. So I forked it in a new stackblitz and made it correct. Here the new [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mip5sn)

Comment: Thank u for your continuous response.The above code retain the value always 0 when add the products to cart

Comment: Well, this is just to show you how it should work, I guess you have to adapt the logic, specially in the `map` function : I've supposed the product count is in `httpResponse.body.length` but I'm surely wrong because I don't know how your httpResponse is formatted.

Answer (score 0):

try this, like Observables should be subscribed and Promises should be executed like this.
[promise](https://angular.io/guide/comparing-observables#creation-and-subscription)

```
ngOnInit() { 
      this.cartService.getCart().then(
           (cartItems)=>{
                this.cartItem = <CartItem[]>cartItems.body;
         }
       );
}
```

Comment: why always told the difference between observable and promise.I know that already, but this is not a problem and solution for this.

Comment: then create stackblitz project then only one can understand the problem

Comment: i'm not telling the difference, here i mentioned subscription of promise

Comment: I was clearly told what's the problem in above query.